# 'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: node.js, typescript

> src/db/models/point.ts:10:11 - error TS2693: 'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

```
const PointSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    index: true,
  },
  point: {
    type: number,
    required: true,
  },
});

export interface PointProp extends Document {
  id: string;
  point: number;
}

export default model<PointProp>('point', PointSchema);
```

Comment: And you already searched SO for `error TS2693` and checked some of those posts and none of them helped?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i'm beginner. Can't you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a TypeScript `type` inside an object, as value, just as what the error says. You should have given more info, but I am guessing you are working with Mongoose. In that case, `number` (the [TypeScript type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#number)) should be [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) (the object)

```js
const PointSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    index: true,
  },
  point: {
    type: Number, // <---
    required: true,
  },
});
```

See https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a typo. change number to Number

```
 point: {
    type: **Number**,
    required: true,
  },
```